# Обрезка изображения на клиенте или на сервере?

Tags: javascript, php, сервер, клиент-сервер

Подскажите на какой стороне лучше резать изображение? Сам сайт на ограниченное посещение пользователей нагрузка не должна быть большей (на там на сервере другие сайты лежат). Будет ли проблемой для сервера обрезать изображения или лучше делать это на стороне клиента, нужно обрезать фото клиентов и сжимать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрезка изображений, особенно фото/аватары пользователей лучше всего проводить на стороне клиента. Вот список причин:

1. **Снижается нагрузка на сервер.**
   Даже если в Вашем случае нагрузка будет незначительной, зачем оставлять её при возможности избежать.
2. **Возможность для пользователя управлять обрезкой фото.**
   Если Вы не планируете сейчас добавлять редактор картинок, это не означает что так будет всегда. В современном вебе "редактор аватара" уже само собой разумеющееся.

Исключением может являться требование поддержки старых браузеров, в которых попросту нельзя работать с `canvas`

Comment: да основная проблема в том что пользователи учебные заведения и там всякие ie win xp до сих пор стоит

Comment: мда, это самый неприятный кейс, но я бы всё таки тогда реализовал оба подхода, где первый с редактором на клиенте был бы взглядом в светлое будущее, а второй альтернативный просто тихо обрезал на сервере. На клиенте проверял "браузер на совместимость" и в зависимости от этого показывал ту или иную страницу/вьюху

Comment: да я так решил сделать, все равно придется заливать несколько файлов. менеджер для админки сделаю, если что будут править. а фотов профиле при добавлении через скрипт